Python subprocess function unable to load library
I am trying to execute a Java jar file via a subprocess.run() function in Python. When I execute the jar file via Java as normally performed a necessary library is found. In this case, the library is the netCDF library. However, when I use the subprocess function, the library is not found.
Even when I explicitly tell the subprocess function to look to the netcdf directory, the library is still not found. I perform the call like this:
java_env = dict(os.environ)
java_env['PATH'] = f'{java_env["PATH"]};C:\\Program Files\\netCDF 4.9.2\\bin'

result = subprocess.run(
         ['java', '-jar', jar_path],
         capture_output = True,
         text = True,
         env=java_env)

The goal of the Python routine is to call a Java jar that writes out a netCDF file. I expected the library to be found, and a netCDF file to be written out to disk. I receive the following error when running the Python routine:
[main] WARN serverStartup - Nc4Iosp: NetCDF-4 C library not present (jna_path='null', libname='netcdf').
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'netcdf':
The specified procedure could not be found.

The specified procedure could not be found.

The specified module could not be found.

Native library (win32-x86-64/netcdf.dll) not found in resource path (C:/Users/rwal/projects/target/AddLightningLayer.jar)

I also ensured that the netcdf library is in my Windows Path variable. It is necessary to use Java because I need to use an API that is written in Java. Unfortunately, there is no Python equivalent to the Java based API.
I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.10.4, and JDK 17.
Thanks for your help.

I don't know Python but you might try, before '-jar', something like the following: '-Djava.library.path=C:\whatever-is-the-parent-diretory-of\win32-x86-64'

Python is probably not at issue here at all. OP has left out that they are using the netCDF-Java library to try to interact with the netCDF-C library via JNA, which is evident by mention of the Nc4Iosp class in the error message. So I think we need to see OP's Java code that is calling into the netCDF-Java library to do things.

The error message is related to resource path, not library path. Most likely the missing DLL is bundled inside a related jar which is not referenced in classpath. ie try -cp launcher or maybe see if can use manifest

Actually I think that error is coming from JNA itself, so if the runtime parameter I posted doesn't help, then the following ones might throw more light on things: -Djna.debug_load=true and -Djna.debug_load.jna=true

The line "Nc4Iosp: NetCDF-4 C library not present (jna_path='%s', libname='%s')." is straight out of the netCDF-Java class NetcdfLibrary, lines 135-136. Which for some reason the logger object in use there was created at the start of the class with "serverStartup" as its ID.
